# Polymer 1.0 on-tap event's target is child

Tags: events, polymer

I'm using on-tap to detect element clicks.

```
<div id="parent" on-tap="myclickEvent">
    <h1>Some text<h1>
</div>
```

But when i click on it, the target attribute in the fired event is the h1.
How do I change to make the parent element be the target?

Answer (score 9):

Try `e.currentTarget`. Don't expect it to be shown in `console.log` though as that browser function is asynchronous in Chrome (actually don't even bother logging event objects or objects inside events). But you can see it actually returns a `div` if you try this in your code.

```
myclickEvent: function(e){
  ...
  var tag = e.currentTarget.tagName;
  console.log(tag);
}
```

Comment: I came across this issue because my usage of the event.target was working onconsistantly. Sometimes it got the direct parent, other times the parent's parent (this was the case testing the exact same element many times.) Not sure why, but you "currentTarget" returns the correct parent every time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

here is very useful notes you should take care of:

- make sure your element has a unique id (this is very important)
- if your element inside the template use event.currentTarget
- if your element inside the content (shady DOM or shadow DOM) use `Polymer.dom(event).rootTarget`

Comment: isn't the element inside the the template inside shadow dom?

Comment: when you pass your element to the component content area
<my-com><input id="my-element" /></my-com> some polymer components will then take this element and replace it in the template after rendering the template using special tag called <content> for example <content select="input"></content>  in this case your element will be in the shadow dom